# How to make my website look the same on all screens?

Tags: php, html, web, responsive, desktop

How can I make my website: informatiestuderen.nl on small screen (for example on phone) look the same as on big screen like desktop (computer)?

Because my website doesn't work at all on phone.

For example this website: carrieretijger.nl looks the same on phone as on desktop.

I would like to be able to zoom in on the website on small screen.

Comment: I don't recommend designing websites with a horizontal scroll bar. That makes its navigation a little difficult on phones.

Comment: Seriously, you don't want it to look the _same_. That will make a terrible experience for your mobile users. Instead you want to make a different version which displays the same content (or a subset of it which is most relevant, if there's too much), using a design which works on a smaller screen and with touch input. Google "Responsive Design" to get the general idea of the concept. You must have seen lots of mobile websites, right? Compare them to the desktop versions of the same sites. Hopefully you'll see what I mean. That carrieretijger.nl site is a great example of how **not** to do it!

Answer (score 1):

That should be default behaviour on phones!

Most sites need to include a line of code such as `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` to avoid that behaviour from happening.

See [Responsive Web Design - The Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) (w3schools).

However, if you wanted to enforce the opposite behaviour, you could choose a width at which your site looks good and tell browsers to always use that. For example, if you decided on a width of `960px`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=960px">
```

Note: this tag goes inside the `head` section of your page.

---

An additional comment: I would recommend making your page responsive, for example using CSS `@media` queries. Horizontal scrolling tends to be quite annoying!

Here is the advice from the w3schools link:

> 1. Do NOT use large fixed width elements - For example, if an image is displayed at a width wider than the viewport it can cause the viewport to scroll horizontally. Remember to adjust this content to fit within the width of the viewport.
> 2. Do NOT let the content rely on a particular viewport width to render well - Since screen dimensions and width in CSS pixels vary widely between devices, content should not rely on a particular viewport width to render well.
> 3. Use CSS media queries to apply different styling for small and large screens - Setting large absolute CSS widths for page elements will cause the element to be too wide for the viewport on a smaller device. Instead, consider using relative width values, such as width: 100%. Also, be careful of using large absolute positioning values. It may cause the element to fall outside the viewport on small devices.